# Uncaught Error: The property or field has not been initialized

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-apps

I am trying to run the following code in a simple sharepoint app, but I got this error:

```
Uncaught Error: The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.
```

Code is this one:

```
var collListItems;
$(document).ready(function () {
    getConfigValues();
});
function getConfigValues() {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var configList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Configuration Values');
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    collListItems = configList.getItems(camlQuery);
    context.load(collListItems);
    context.executeQueryAsync(onGetConfigValuesSuccess, onGetConfigValuesFail);
}
function onGetConfigValuesSuccess() {
    var OrgLogoUrl;
    var OrgName;
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItems.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        var current = oListItem.get_item('Title');
        switch (current) {
            case 'OrganizationName':
                OrgName = oListItem.get_item('Value');
                break;
            case 'OrganizationLogoUrl':
                OrgLogoUrl = oListItem.get_item('Value');
                break;
        };
    }
    if (OrgName && OrgName.length > 0) {
        $('#DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea').html(OrgName);
        $('.ms-siteicon-img').attr('title', OrgName);
    }
    if (OrgLogoUrl && OrgLogoUrl.length > 0)
        $('.ms-siteicon-img').attr('src', OrgLogoUrl);
    else
        $('.ms-siteicon-img').attr('src', '../Images/AppLogo.png');
}
function onGetConfigValuesFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Failed to get the Configuration Values. Error:' + args.get_message());
}
```

The code is from a book, without any modifications:

```
OrgName = oListItem.get_item('Value');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The specified error could occur due to one of the following reasons:

1. Column with Internal Name `Value` does **not** exist in the List `Configuration Values`

   Since [SP.ListItem.item property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245189(v=office.15).aspx)  expects field Internal Name, please make sure the field with such a name exists in List.
2. List Item value for a field `Value` could not be loaded implicitly.

   The solution: try explicitly specify what List Item properties to
   load using [SP.ClientContext.load method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn168903(v=office.15).aspx). Replace the line:

   ```
   context.load(collListItems);
   ```

   with

   ```
   context.load(collListItems,'Include(Title,Value)');
   ```

Comment: In my case, I had to open the Schema.xml file for the ConfigurationValues list. I noticed that the Internal Name given was "Value1", not "Value". Changing either the script to use Value1 or the list internal name to be Value fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Please change `Value` to `Value1` in `App.js` file and it'll work fine for you if not then please click on the Value field in the Configuration Values List and check for internal name in the URL, here you'll find the exact internal name of you column Value.
[image: See internal name of the Value field]

```
OrgName = oListItem.get_item('Value1');
```

[image]